# password attribute filling unwanted usernameand password

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to create a login page in php.

I got the form and the login verificaion works fine but when i go to my `index.php` which is my log in page, the login credentials are auto filled with unwanted credentials like below.

[image]

Whereas my login paage should look like this..

[image]

My form is as below:

```
<form action="check_login.php" method="post">
    <label id="uname">User Name: </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required="required"> <br>
    <label id="psw">Password: </label><input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required="required"> <br> <br>
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login </button>
</form>
```

When I use `type=text` it works fine..

I've also tried `autocomplete="off"`, but it doesn't work...

What am I doing wrong? I'm a newbie... Please help me...

Comment: Just search "Remove saved password [your-browser-name]"

Comment: question updated

Comment: just add autocomplete off `<form action="" method="get" autocomplete="on">`

Comment: Tried it.. Doesn't workk... Question updated

Comment: Is it still auto fill if you open it with other browser?

Comment: The problem seems to be that this is a "login" form, MDN has some infos on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields

Comment: Yes, also I have no user named localhost.. never used it.. so it cant save an unused username... also when i try to print the password that is filled ... it has some garbade value @Christ

Comment: Then try to remove that user from the "Saved Logins" in your browser preferences

Comment: Okiee.. Got it @kerbholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...removed the user from saved logins from my browser.... And it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required="required">
```

with

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
```

it is browser feature to auto fill the form

Answer (score 1):

"Autofilling" a form is a browser feature. You can turn it off for a form using the `autocomplete` attribute (setting it to `off`). Change your form to

```
<form action="check_login.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label id="uname">User Name: </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required="required"> <br>
    <label id="psw">Password: </label><input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required="required"> <br> <br>
    <button type="submit" name="login">Login </button>
</form>
```

There might be cases where `autocomplete="off"` is set, but the browser still fills in your form details. The "trick" is to set `autocomplete` to an invalid value, like `autocomplete="kerbholz"`.